# Optimize query performance having inner join on multiple tables - MS SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, query-optimization

I am looking into improving the query performance. Table structure and query is as below:

There are 5 tables:

Base (Id, column1) primary clustred index on (Id)
A(Id, column1, column2, Last_updated_date) composite primary clustered index on (Id,Last_updated_date)

B(Id, column1, column2, Last_updated_date) composite primary clustered index on (Id,Last_updated_date)

C(Id, column1, column2, Last_updated_date) composite primary clustered index on (Id,Last_updated_date)

D(Id, column1, column2, Last_updated_date) composite primary clustered index on (Id,Last_updated_date)

E(Id, column1, column2, Last_updated_date) composite primary clustered index on (Id,Last_updated_date)

No of rows in Base table is 50k and in rest of the tables it is 800k

Query I'm trying to optimize:

```
select * from Base base

inner join A a on a.Id = base.id and a.last_updated_date between '2000-01-01' and '2015-12-31'

inner join B b on b.Id = base.id and b.last_updated_date = a.last_updated_date

inner join C c on c.Id = base.id and c.last_updated_date = a.last_updated_date

inner join D d on d.Id = base.id and d.last_updated_date = a.last_updated_date

inner join E e on e.Id = base.id and e.last_updated_date = a.last_updated_date
```

In brief, above query is retrieving all available information from all tables for Id's which are in base table.

I've observed below by looking into plan:

1. out of these 5 tables, tables C and D have cost of around 40% each. Table E is having 0% cost.
2. For table C and D, optimizer is choosing merger join while for other it is choosing nested loop join.
3. For table C and D, index scan is performed while for rest of tables index seek is performed.
4. I tried to force nested loop join for all. so optimizer chooses nested loop join for all. In that case, for some of the tables even index seek is taking 40% cost while some of the tables have 0% cost.
   No improvement on execution time.

My questions are:

1. Despite the fact all tables having same index structure, why it is taking more cost for some of the tables?
2. Any suggestion on how to improve the query performance?

Answer (score 0):

1. I would move your BETWEEN to the WHERE clause. This is more common and I've seen query optimizers choke up when leaving it as part of the join.

   select * from Base base
   inner join A a on a.Id = base.i
   inner join B b on b.Id = base.id and b.last_updated_date = a.last_updated_date
   inner join C c on c.Id = base.id and c.last_updated_date = a.last_updated_date
   inner join D d on d.Id = base.id and d.last_updated_date = a.last_updated_date
   inner join E e on e.Id = base.id and e.last_updated_date = a.last_updated_date
   WHERE a.last_updated_date between '2000-01-01' and '2015-12-31'
2. Is ID an number type column? Numbers are much faster for lookups than strings.
3. Make sure you have indexes on all ID columns, and last_update_date columns.

Comment: Tried this approach but didn't have any improvement on execution times, logical reads or physical reads.  2 of the tables are having more than 30 columns and only those tables are contributing towards most of the cost.

Answer (score 0):

I had such a case. I was getting poor performance because of outdated statistics. what you can do is, Update table statistics for all tables OR use HASH JOIN.